# Need suggestion for tag improvement

Tags: discussion, tags

A [fitting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitting) tag was requested for [Forward Shoulder Adjustment in Knitted Sweaters](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/forward-shoulder-adjustment-in-knitted-sweaters).  It sounded like a good tag and I created it.  Then I searched for other questions that might benefit from the same tag.  I hadn't thought of the fact that "fitting" is also commonly used in jewelry and other applications to refer to various physical objects.  So the term has multiple meanings, and the tag is likely to cause confusion and poor search results.

Is there another common term for the act of adjusting clothing that is unique to that meaning that we can use instead for this tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tailor](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailor) or [tailoring](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailoring) could work.

Another option is to combine words: [clothing-fitting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing-fitting), [jewelry-fitting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewelry-fitting), and whatever other field it applies to.

The second option will make it easier to find, I think, and we can always synonymise both tags.

Comment: I like your combined word option.  When the user starts to type "fitting", both options will show up and they can pick the right one if there's more than one (or see that the tag doesn't apply).  Brilliant!

Comment: I'm going to wait to make the change so the question can appear on the main page for awhile under the OP's name.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 terms typically associated with making garments fit.

## Tailoring

This is almost exclusively limited to constructing and altering suiting.  However, a lot of people incorrectly use it to mean the same thing as "alterations".  If you buy a book on tailoring, it will typically focus on suit coats, jackets, or blazers.  Pants may also be included, but a lot less print is dedicated to it.

## Alterations

This typically refers to adjusting how a constructed garment fits.  Because finished garments have very small seam allowances, you're rather limited to what you can actually do to make it fit.  There are outliers with generous seam allowances in strategic locations, like bridal and formal gowns or men's dress pants, so you can let them out.  Most of the time, you're limited to taking in seams or shortening hems.

## Fitting

This term is used to broadly cover anything related to making garments fit.  Someone who goes to try on a garment for alterations, or to try on a garment that has already been altered to make sure the adjustments are correct, might say they are "going in for a fitting."

Doing a quick browsing of books on Amazon, "fitting" is used more frequently than "alterations" if what you're looking for is making patterns fit before the garment is cut and constructed.  You may see both terms together, such as "how to fit and alter patterns."

---

[Alterations] could just as easily be misused as [fitting].  A combination of terms could make it more clear, such as [fitting-and-alterations].  However, some people will see that a tag contains the word they want and just go with it anyway, regardless of what it actually means.  On StackOverflow, there is a tag called [snap-framework] that is literally for a web framework called Snap, written in Haskell.  I used to remove this tag all the time from questions about making something "snap" to another object, like "snap to grid" in image editing software.

Whatever you do, don't use "tailoring" unless you're actually talking about suiting.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks.

Comment: And thanks for the information on the terminology :)